# Error con operador in en python

Tags: python

Tengo la siguiente estructura:
`[['P', 'L', 'A', 'Y', 'F']]` que trata de simular una matriz, le inserté una lista antes que funciona como un renglón. El problema es que no quiero tener repetidos en la matriz, así que utilizo el operador in para saber cuales elementos ya he guardado. Pero al momento de utilizar, por ejemplo `print('A' in matriz)`, me arroja el resultado `False`, no entiendo porqué si la 'A' efectivamente está en la matriz.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿por qué pasa esto y qué puedo hacer para buscar la 'A')

Comment: Nop, el elemento `A` no se encuentra en el conjunto `lista`. El conjunto`lista` tiene un solo elemento que es una lista que tiene 3 elementos. Lo que debes haces es `print('A' in lista[0])` o podrías usar un `for` así `for element in lista: print("A" in element)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La lista

```
lista = [['P', 'L', 'A', 'Y', 'F']]
```

contiene un solo elemento (`lista[0]`), que es una lista de letras:

```
['P', 'L', 'A', 'Y', 'F']
```

Lo que debes hacer es buscar dentro del primer elemento de la lista

```
lista = [['P', 'L', 'A', 'Y', 'F']]

print('A' in lista)  #  No funciona
print('A' in lista[0]) # Si funciona
```

produce:

```
False
True

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Entiendo, gracias !